# Business on a tourist Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, business-travel

I currently hold a type C Schengen visa, valid for one year. Initially I applied for it for tourism. However, next week I am going to visit our headquarters in Germany and also our company party. Costs are covered by the company. Just to be safe I asked the company for the hotel booking but they won’t provide it for me as they have an agreement with the hotel I am staying at. Instead, my company has provided me with a letter stating I am going for business purposes and events (when I’m only visiting our warehouse n attending the party). Border force usually doesn’t ask any question when I arrive in the schengen area but in this case would a valid tourist visa be ok to go on this “business trip”?